# Silex - weird cache behaviour

Tags: caching, silex

I have been developing the website with Silex and I experienced that the frontend just doesn't update immediately when I upload an image from the backend. Even I set the cache mode to be false it seems not to fix the problem.

So how can i disable cache/ refresh cache so it can update at frontend side? Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Seem rather like browser cache. If you can, try changing link to your images to include modification timestamp in query string (ex instead of http://example.com/image.jpg use http://example.com/image.jpg?ts=123456789)

Comment: @dev-null-dweller im think this website has the strongest cache i have ever seen, do you mean that this is browser's problem more than the website itself?